# If a file was found more than once in subfolders - delete all using batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

The system I'm working on looks like this:

```
D:\TargetFolder\Subfolder1 
D:\TargetFolder\Subfolder2\Subfolder3
```

There is a file called **"Settings.txt"** that could exist in each of these folders. what I want is the following:

- **If** the file was found more than once in the targeted folder and all of its subfolders **then** delete all of them.
- **If** the file was found just once in the targeted folder and all of its subfolders **then** continue on with the script.
- **If** the file doesn't exist **then** continue on with the script.

The final script could possibly be something like this:

```
IF exist "D:\TargetFolder\*Settings.txt" (goto delete) else goto continue
:delete
del *Settings.txt /f /q
:continue
exit
```

I hope I explained my question correctly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /F "skip=1" %%a in ('dir /B /S D:\TargetFolder\Settings.txt 2^>NUL') do (
   del /Q /S D:\TargetFolder\Settings.txt >NUL
   goto break
)
:break
```

The `for /F` loop process file names from `dir /S` command, but the first one is skipped (because `"skip=1"`switch), that is to say, if there are *more than one file*, the next commands are executed.

The first command in the `for` deletes all files with "Settings.txt" name and the `for` is break because the `goto` command.

Answer (score 1):

This batch file could be used for the task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SettingsFile="
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "D:\TargetFolder\Settings.txt" /A-D-L /B /S 2^>nul') do if not defined SettingsFile (set "SettingsFile=1") else (del "D:\TargetFolder\Settings.txt" /A /F /Q /S >nul 2>nul & goto Continue)
:Continue
endlocal
```

A less compact variant of above:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SettingsFile="
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "D:\TargetFolder\Settings.txt" /A-D-L /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    if not defined SettingsFile (
        set "SettingsFile=1"
    ) else (
        del "D:\TargetFolder\Settings.txt" /A /F /Q /S >nul 2>nul
        goto Continue
    )
)
:Continue
endlocal
```

First, there is made sure that the environment variable `SettingsFile` is not defined by chance.

Next the command **DIR** is executed by a separate command process started in background to search in `D:\TargetFolder` for files with name `Settings.txt` and output them all with full path. The output of **DIR** is captured by **FOR** and processed line by line if **DIR** found the file `Settings.txt` at all.

The environment variable `SettingsFile` is defined with a string value which does not really matter on first file `Settings.txt`. The **FOR** loop finishes without having done anything else if there is no more file `Settings.txt`.

But on second file `Settings.txt` is executed the command **DEL** to delete in the specified folder and all its subfolders the file `Settings.txt`. The loop is excited with command **GOTO** to continue batch file processing on the line below label `Continue` as the other occurrences of `Settings.txt` do not matter anymore and of course do not exist anymore on deletion of all `Settings.txt` was successful.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul` and `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `cmd.exe /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not difficult if you can use the PowerShell already on your Windows system. If the count of files found is greater than zero, then each one is deleted. Otherwise, nothing happens. When you are confident that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` command.

```
@powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path 'C:\TargetFolder' -Filter 'Settings.txt';" ^
    "if ($Files.Count -gt 1) {" ^
        "foreach ($File in $Files) { Remove-Item $File.FullName -Whatif }" ^
    "}"
```

Some of the noise can be eliminated if it could be run as a PowerShell .ps1 script file.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path 'C:\TargetFolder' -Filter 'Settings.txt'
if ($Files.Count -gt 1) {
    foreach ($File in $Files) { Remove-Item $File.FullName -Whatif }
}
```